# Access Value of While Loop Outside it

Tags: php, loops

The code that contained elements fetched from array

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * from room";
$query_run = @mysql_query($query);
?>
<?php 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
$id = $row['id'];
?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;  ?>" />
<td> <center><a href=<?php echo "dell_rooms.php?id=$id";?>><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></a></center></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td>
<td><button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"><center><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Remove</center></button></a></td>
</tr>
```

The Delete Confirmation Modal that Show upon click on above Remove button

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div>
  <a href="dell_rooms.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Remove</button></a>

<button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
```

The Output is repeated as the last value fetched

```
dell_rooms.php?id=10
dell_rooms.php?id=10
dell_rooms.php?id=10
```

I want it to be like this :

```
dell_rooms.php?id=8
dell_rooms.php?id=9
dell_rooms.php?id=10
```

not only the last element fetched

Note that the id i used in Modal is outside while loop and if i put the modal inside loop it not work properly

Comment: Either put modal in loop and create one modal per row, and set target and id dynamically or use javascript to update href of a single modal based on which button was clicked

Comment: how can i do that please

Comment: there is a button for delete in the table and delete in the modal?

Comment: *"how can i do that please"* .. do what?

Comment: yes the first just to show the deletion confirmation and the second to perform delete

Comment: With one modal for each row? Just need to make the modal ID unique, and the data-target to match. Can do something like `id="delete_<?php echo $id;?>"` and same for `data-target`

Comment: please write it for me here

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447170/getting-variable-value-outside-array#comment64299937_38447170) uses the same page name... ( As a matter of fact, the whole question seems quite like the other)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop using mysql_* Functions because it's omitted on php 7.0 instead use mysqli_* or PDO.

I advise you to read through this. it will help you to migrate from mysql to mysqli [Converting to MySQLi](https://github.com/philip/MySQLConverterTool).

i found alot of bugs on your code

you didn't close the while loop and there was a double quote missing on the html maybe just a typo

```
<a href="<?php echo "dell_rooms.php?id=$id";?> >
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></a>
```

give this one a try it worked fine with me

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * from room";
$query_run = @mysql_query($query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
$id = $row['id'];
?>
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;  ?>" />
<td>
<center>
<a href="<?php echo "dell_rooms.php?id=$id";?>><input type="checkbox" class="myCheckBox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></a>
</center>
</td>
<td><?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td>
<td><button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"><center><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Remove</center></button></a></td>
</tr>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```